# SpringAOP: How is spring able to proxy object created by factory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am new to AOP and slowly reading up and learning SpringAOP and AspectJ.

I have run into an un-expected example that an object which is not created as a bean but is created by a factory which is created as a bean is being proxied with my aspect, while I am expecting only the objects that are being created by spring to be proxied with applicable aspects in SpringAOP.

How is spring able to know to proxy an object that is being created by a factory which was registered with spring? Meaning how would spring know that my own factory is in fact a factory and the object returned by `DogShelter.getAngryDog()` is a new object that needs to be wrapped with proxy instead of some existing `AngryDog` which has previously been already wrapped with a aspect proxy?

Here is the code:

Object:

```
public class AngryDog extends Dog {
    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("AngryDog->play()");
        bark();
        bite();
    }

    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("AngryDog->bark()");
    }

    @Override
    public void bite() {
        System.out.println("AngryDog->bite()");
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class DogShelter {
    public AngryDog getAngryDog(){
        return new AngryDog();
    }
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class BeforeAllDogMethodsAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.demos.dogs.*.*(..)))")
    public void doAccessCheck() {
        System.out.println("SpringAOP aspect called!");
    }

}
```

Spring Config:

```
/** DogConfig spring configuration */
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
public class DogConfig {

    @Bean
    public AngryDog dog() {
        return new AngryDog();
    }

    @Bean
    public DogShelter dogShelter(){
        return new DogShelter();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeforeAllDogMethodsAspect beforeAngryDogBitesExample(){
        return new BeforeAllDogMethodsAspect();
    }
}
```

invocation:

```
foo(){
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("Getting a dog from locally created dog shelter. And playing with it");
        DogShelter locallyCreatedDogShelter = new DogShelter();
        AngryDog dogFromLocalShelter = locallyCreatedDogShelter.getAngryDog();
        dogFromLocalShelter.play();

        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("Getting a dog from autowired dog shelter. And playing with it");
        AngryDog dogFromAutoWiredDogShelter = autowiredDogShelter.getAngryDog();
        dogFromAutoWiredDogShelter.play();
}
```

Output :

```
 ----------------
 Getting a dog from locally created dog shelter. And playing with it
 AngryDog->play()
 AngryDog->bark()
 AngryDog->bite()
 ----------------
 Getting a dog from autowired dog shelter. And playing with it
 SpringAOP aspect called!
 AngryDog->play()
 AngryDog->bark()
 AngryDog->bite()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should display the method name in your aspect. Otherwise, you don´t know which method is being intercepted.

Concerning your question: Probably what is being intercepted is the getAngryDog() method and not the play() method.

Comment: Added method name being intercepted. Was exactly what you thought `getAngryDog()`  was being intercepted.